# Where do you think, we are in?

Tags: prepositions, questions, grammar-myths

> Where do you think, we are in?

What's wrong with this sentence? My editor says the following comment.

Review this sentence for preposition use, particularly at the end of sentences               The preposition, “in”, is at the end of a sentence.  Consider re-wording your sentence so the preposition is not at the end. In informal cases, we often end a sentence with a preposition.  When writing formally, ending a sentence with a preposition should be avoided.  Prepositions are words like on, in, to, with, from, about and through.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? "Where do you think? We are in?" or "In where do you think we are?" or something else?

Comment: I find it strange that your editor focuses on ending the sentence with a preposition when the sentence itself doesn't seem to make sense. Can you add some more surrounding context, or explain what meaning you're looking for?

Comment: This looks like a comment from grammar checker, not an editor. If it's from an editor, then he or she isn't competent. The first problem is the comma after _think_. The S should be: _Where do you think we are?_ That claptrap about not ending sentences with prepositions in formal writing is nonsense. Ignore it.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "editor" you mean "Microsoft Word".  As @BillFranke says, you can safely ignore its advice here.

Comment: I wonder if the implication is (as @Hellion suggests) *text* editor, rather than a professional (human) editor.

Comment: @BillFranke,@WendiKidd, By editor I mean the spellcheck software editor. What I mean by the question is "In where do you think we are?". But I wrote it like "Where do you think, we are in?" because this is for spoken english, not for written english. I have seen people speak like this. So my question whether what I wrote is correct or my editor is correct?

Comment: @WendiKidd the context is, assume I take my friend to a place without his knowledge, I ask him "where do you think, we are in?"

Comment: In that case, the word "in" is an unnecessary, added extra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget what your grammar checker says, having a preposition at the end of the sentence isn't a problem in general.  The problem is that, in this case, the sentence just doesn't make sense as written.  Based on your comments describing what you would like to say, the sentence you want to write is:

> "Where do you think we are?"

Which has the meaning of "In what place do you think we are currently located?", except it's more standard spoken English.