# Difference between anyone and anybody?

Tags: word-usage, difference, indefinite-pronouns

As per google meaning I understood like,

Anyone - any person or any people

Anybody - anyone

It seems both are relevant. I am trying to understand the proper place for using these words. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference.

[Cambridge's reference:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/anyone-anybody-or-anything)

Anyone and anybody have no difference in meaning. Anybody is a little *less formal* than anyone. Anyone is used *more in writing* than anybody:

```
I didn’t know anybody at the party.
```

[talking about the New Zealand rugby team, the All Blacks]

```
It is hard to find anyone who thinks that the All Blacks will face a stronger team.
```

Comment: [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24865/ms-word-does-not-like-any-body-and-corrects-it-to-anybody) might interest you

Answer (score 4):

As Maulik wrote, they are interchangeable with only slight differences in formailty.

One common pitfall that I have seen learners fall into is the creating the negative forms of these words. *Nobody* is a single word, but the negative friend of *anyone* is *no one*, which cannot be written as one word.

Comment: yes, but good to note that 'none' is also a word!

Comment: Correct! It does not necessarily have the same meaning as "no one", though.

Comment: Hi @ Aaron, Thank you for your valuable reply. Thank you for one more additional information on "No one" and "None". :-)