# agreement of the word augur

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> 1) Sustained growth in consumer spending and heightened health
>   awareness augur well for the health and wellness beverage industry in
>   China.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ? The word processor indicated a mistake in using "augur", "augurs" seemed to be the right word to use.

Comment: Ignore the [grammar checker](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker): you have a compound subject, *growth* and *awareness*, so a plural verb.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, 'Augur' is not a common word in American English. But, based on its definition, the sentence is grammatical and makes sense. However, I would advise using a more common word/expression than "augur well"—perhaps "bode well."

> Sustained growth in consumer spending and heightened health awareness bode well for the health and wellness beverage industry in China.

Comment: *bode*, plural: *Growth...and awareness*, two different things. But I doubt *bode* is more 'common' than 'augur'.

Comment: If one were to integrate the NGrams of these terms to determine the total volume of usage over time of each term, 'augur' would clearly win. A Google NGram confirms, though, that there has been a higher incidence of the word 'bode' than 'augur' since 1989.

Comment: However, 'augurs' (singular) has now recovered against 'bodes'! Digging a little deeper, AmE prefers 'bode/s', BrE prefers 'augur/s'. But as of 2008 the differences (max 1.4:1) are not, I think, significant.

Comment: I see. I'm speaking from an American English standpoint--the obvious source of my bias towards bode. I've never heard 'augur' used before like this. If I heard it in conversation, I'd think you were talking about an 'auger' as in a drilling device.

Comment: [COCA (American English)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=32226989) versus [BNC (British English)](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=32227006)