# Why is "for the union dues to be collected" rather than "for the union dues to collect"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> It means that the NUM will have to arrange locally for the union dues
> **to be collected** individually.

There are many sentences which are active:

> 1. If so, and if we assume that abstract grammatical principles which are
>    universal are part of our biological endowment, then the natural
>    conclusion **to reach** is that (7) is a principle which is
>    biologically wired into the language faculty, and which thus forms
>    part of our genetic make-up.
> 2. Perhaps the first thing **to mention** is that all the speakers/writers are 'important' people - compare this with the second newspaper story on the strike, below.
> 3. If (as Chomsky claims) human beings are biologically endowed with an innate language faculty, an obvious question **to ask** is what is
>    the nature of the language faculty.

So, why is "for the union dues **to be collected**" passive?

Comment: You seem to have heard the opinion that use of the passive is wrong or suboptimal ([making this a duplicate of this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/why-shall-passive-voice-be-rephrased)), but [that simply isn't true and the passive is useful and valid](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922). It could certainly be changed to e.g. "It means that the NUM will have to arrange locally for someone to collect the union dues" but that is probably worse because it changes focus from the individual collection to other topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your example sentences, the speaker/writer is reaching the conclusion, mentioning a fact, or asking a question.

The union dues (payments from members) are not collecting anything, they are *being collected*.  There are many passive sentences as well as active ones!

> I am waiting for a parcel *to be delivered.*
>
> I have asked *to be notified* as soon as he arrives.

Comment: Is the passive used here because "I" is not the logical subject of 'deliver'?

Comment: The parcel is not delivering anything, the postal service or delivery company are going to deliver it.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to use them in the passive voice? Namely,to be reached, to be mentioned, to be asked?

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: I find myself unable to succinctly explain why all of OP's three "infinitive" examples could be validly (albeit it perhaps "awkwardly") replaced by ***to be reached, to be mentioned, to be asked***. But *...arrange locally for the union dues **to collect** individually* doesn't seem like just an "awkward" alternative - it's out-and-out invalid.