# what is wrong with "You hope you can live in a world which could exactly match your own value"?

Tags: relative-clauses

I got a auto-spell fix hint in Microsoft word saying that

> You hope you can live in a world which could exactly match your own value.

should be

> You hope you can live in a world, which could exactly match your own value.

or

> You hope you can live in a world that could exactly match your own value.

Do I have to change this? Is there any materials to read for reference?

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/103103whichthat.htm) helpful.

Comment: It seems we should add a `,` after `which` and can omit it after `that`?

Comment: I guess it's flagging that after **which** is an adjectival clause.  The reason for the switch between which -> that is **a world** is singular and specific, if you changes the original sentence to **live in worlds**, it may only suggest **which**. Just a guess...

Comment: [When to Trust Your Grammar Checker? Almost never.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker)

Comment: Why would anyone want to live in a world that *could* match your own value (whatever that means). I would hope to live in a world that can match my value(s?). *"You hope you can live in a world which **can** exactly match your own value"?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to change this. However, I would phrase it like this:

> "You hope to live in a world exactly matching your own values."

We can all hope for that, but I wonder if it is ever actually possible.