# Double restrictive clause

Tags: restrictive-clauses

I want to say this following sentence.

> The decisions in making a project plan that **are** affected by variable X
>   **are** presented in Table 4.1

However, the grammarly, a grammar software, says that my sentence should be

> The decisions in making a project plan that **is** affected by variable X
>   **is** presented in Table 4.1

The software argues that the "be" explain the word "plan". Meanwhile, I want to explain the word "decisions" instead of "plan".

How should I write the proper sentence?

Thank you

Comment: I think that software takes the immediate neighbor of **that** as the reference. By the way, I guess "the decisions in making a project plan" is not an easy reading. I would say something like "As depicted in Table 4.1, making a project plan includes decisions which are affected by variable X "

Comment: There is _no_ software that can substitute for the hard work of learning English (or any language).

Comment: You're right, grammarly is wrong. See our [Canonical Post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8743/32) on grammar checkers.

Comment: By the way, to eliminate ambiguity about the precedent of _that_, you might rearrange the sentence: _"The decisions that are affected by variable X in making a project plan are presented in Table 4.1."_

Answer (score 1):

Yours is more correct but still sounds odd.  Something like the following may be better:

*The project planning decisions that are affected by variable X are presented in Table 4.1.*

I believe you're right in thinking that Grammarly thinks the variable affects the project plan, while you mean to say that the variable affects the decisions.  Using the noun phrase *project planning decisions* eliminates that ambiguity.

As an aside, I'm more worried about this sentence in your question:

*However, the grammarly, a grammar software, says that my sentence should be*

Grammarly is the name of something so it does not need the definite article.

And software is uncountable so *a grammar software* does not make sense.  Instead you could use *grammar software* or *a grammar software package* or even *a piece of grammar software*.  But never *a software* or *softwares*.