# Is the phrase "these police" or "those police" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[Grammarly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammarly) keeps trying to change it to "this police." I am talking about multiple police. What am I supposed to say in this case?

Comment: *these* and *those* refer to location or picking an item or group, not quantity. You need to use your phrases in a sentence or two with sufficient context to understand the meaning.

Comment: "Police" is a _plurale tantum_. There is no plural form. There is no such form as "a police" or "this police". See the duplicate. Grammarly is wrong. Do not waste your time and money on "grammarly" or similar. See our **[Canonical post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8745/37009)** on grammer "checkers".

Comment: @P.E.Dant: looks like your spell checker may have slipped up...

Comment: @JavaLatte No, it was my fingers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say without an example sentence, but most likely you want to simply say "the police". This phrasing is imprecise in terms of number or location.