# Plural of "one of the few"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

I want to express there are two things with unique characteristics. I know it's an oxymoron, so I'll be glad if you suggest me a better formulation. I would express it either like:

> a) Christianity, Islam and Buddhism are three of the few religions
>   which draw from the older religions.
>
> b) Christianity, Islam and Buddhism are ones of the few religions
>   which draw from the older religions.
>
> c) Christianity, Islam and Buddhism are some of the few religions
>   which draw from the older religions.

The sentences are just examples that popped in my mind.

Comment: Any number of things can have unique characteristics; there is no oxymoron in your first statement. Of your three sentences, the first and third are at least grammatical in English. (You are talking about _three_ things, not _two_, and _"gladder"_ is not a word in English.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Funny, Grammarly suggested me "gladder" instead of "more glad". The examples are just examples. Please edit, if you see anything wrong.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, apparently '**[gladder](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gladder)**' is a word in English. However, it is rarely used in the modern day literature. Here is the **[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gladder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgladder%3B%2Cc0)** to show the word's decline in usage, and perhaps the reason why most of us are unaware of its existance.

Comment: **one of the few** is a common collocation, but **two, three, n of the few** would be an oddity.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, several things can have unique characteristics. But they can't all have the same unique characteristic. (OP: you could say the characteristic is *rare* or *uncommon* rather than unique)

Comment: Ah, I might have known. Grammar checkers like Grammarly are not useful, as this example illustrates. Read our Canonical Post on **[Grammer Checkers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8745/37009)**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**one of the few** is a common collocation, but **two, three, n of the few** would be an oddity.

The typical way of handling this situation is not to bother counting, but to say something like:

> **Of the few X's** that blah blah blah, **A and B** yadda yadda yadda.
>
> **Of the few X's** that blah blah blah, **A, B, and C** yadda yadda yadda.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. How can I apply that to my sentence?

Comment: Of the few religions, which draw from the older religions, there are Christianity, Islam and Buddhism?

Comment: *Of the few religions which draw from the older religions, Christianity, Islam, and Buddhism {have the most adherents}*.   { } is some meaningful predicate that goes beyond stating the fact that they belong to a qualified set.

Comment: If all you want to do is state the fact that A, B, and C belong to a qualified set that contains only a few members:.   *There are only a few religions which draw from older religions; **three of them** are Christianity, Islam, and Buddhism.*

Comment: Ok, sure, I see your point.

Comment: Masterful use of _blah_, but it might benefit from a _yadda_ or, as my Mother was wont to say, _"hamanah hamanah"_, which, as she was quick to admit, was purloined from The Great One.

Comment: @P. E. Dant.  Constructive criticism much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

" ... are among the few ..."

"  ... are among the very few ... "

"  ... are three of only a handful of ..."

"  ... are unusual among religions in that they draw ..."

Comment: But smatterer is cheating with   **of only a handful**   :)   The question is about **few** with a number greater than one.