# cannot be shared or cannot be share?

Tags: future-continuous

Is it totally wrong to say "the report cannot be shared with them"? Based on MS Word it is, it accepts "the report cannot be share with them". Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

**the report cannot be shared with them** is the correct way.  This is an example of [the passive voice](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/), which is made with *to be* + *past participle*.  The past participle of *share* is *shared*, so if someone cannot share the report, then *the report cannot be shared*.

"The report cannot be share with them" is just wrong.  [Don't trust Word's grammar checker, or any English-language grammar checker; none of them is very good.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker)

Comment: The alternative using "***share***" is "**Do not share** with them".